# Dynamic Euchre Tournament - with unknown number of players?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to write some code to programmatically generate partner and table assignments for a progressive euchre tournament. The problem is that I'm not sure how many people will be attending so I want the program to be flexible and accomplish the following tasks:

- Accomodate any number of players (likely somewhere between 20 and 50)
- Randomly assign each player a different partner for every round
- Never assign a player the same partner twice (for instance, if Player2 has Player1 as her partner the first round, they should not be partnered up in any subsequent round)
- If the number of players isn't divisible by 4, that means some people will be sitting out each round. If this is the case, the program will need to make sure that everyone sits out the same number of rounds.

At first, this sounded like an easy program to write but I'm having quite a struggle with it. I've gone about it many different ways but am back at square one now and the tournament is this Friday! At this point, I'm going to have to go the old fashioned way and just assign partners by having them pick numbered pieces of paper out of a hat each round.

Am I over-complicating this? Does anyone have ideas or code examples I could use to get this done?

Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, what you are trying to do would be VERY difficult!  EuchreFun (dot) com is a great resource for Euchre materials. 
There are printables where you could get rotation charts for up to 20 players: http://www.euchrefun.com/p/euchre-printables.html.
There are also ideas for assigning partners for more than 20 players: http://www.euchrefun.com/2013/03/euchre-rotation-charts_18.html.
If you want to do personalized scorecards after you know who is playing, another option is euchre pad (dot)com.
I hope that helps :-)